# xcode 7.3.1 app on iPhone6+ won't play MP3 file anymore

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, avaudioplayer

Xcode app doesn't play MP3 music file on iphone6+ or simulator.
Just trying to play a simple MP3 file when app starts.
Was working.  Tried previous working version, and it won't play.
MP3 filename is d.mp3
It plays if I double-click it in Xcode project.

Xcode top project groups:
ParticleSDK
 ...

myApp
 d.mp3
 all my .h and .c

Pods

I selected:  TARGETS > myApp
Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries:
 AVFoundation
 CoreGraphics
 UIKit
 Foundation

```
        // .h:.............................

        #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
        @interface SparkViewController : UIViewController

        @end


        // .m:........................................

        #import "SparkViewController.h"
        #import "Spark-SDK.h"
        #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
        #import "AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h"

        @interface SparkViewController () <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
        {
             AVAudioPlayer *AV_audio_player;   // strong reference
        }
        @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *loggedInLabel;
        @property (nonatomic, strong) id eventListenerID_A;
        @property (nonatomic, strong) id eventListenerID_B;

        @end

        @implementation SparkViewController

        - (void)viewDidLoad
        {
            [super viewDidLoad];
 //////////////////////////   P L A Y   M P 3   F I L E    ///////////////////////////

                          NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"d" withExtension:@"mp3"];
        printf("\n url = 0x%x \n", (int)url );
        NSError*  the_error;
                      AV_audio_player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error: &the_error];
                      NSLog(@" Error is: %@", the_error );
                          AV_audio_player.delegate = self;
                          [AV_audio_player play];
                          printf( "\n %s    AV_audio_player playing.", __FUNCTION__ );
    printf("\n AV_audio_player = 0x%x", (int)AV_audio_player );

        }
```

OUTPUT LOG...................................
 -[SparkViewController viewDidLoad]   ************* v 2016-09-19 X1  ************
 url = 0x34e5db80
2016-09-19 12:18:41.805 AudMan1 x1[385:60539]  Error is: (null)

-[SparkViewController viewDidLoad]    AV_audio_player playing.
 AV_audio_player = 0x34e51790

Comment: You are throwing away the `error` information. Maybe you should examine it and see if there was an error? — Also please show the results of your NSLog calls.

Comment: Also please note that not every MP3 that plays on your computer will play in iOS.

Comment: Thanks, Matt.  How do I get error info?    And re "not every MP3 plays"...  This file used to play last week.  It was just a simple ditty that I made with MacBook's GarageBand.  I will add error and log output.

Answer (score 0):

All the evidence given in your question would seem to be that the audio player *is* playing, or at least is *starting* to play. Perhaps some *other* code then comes along and stop it, or sets `AV_audio_player` and thus kills the current audio player — but that would be *other* code which you have not shown, so it would be impossible for us to know about it. Only you can find it. When you do, the problem will be solved.

(Of course, you might also have turned on the Silent switch on your iPhone, or turned the volume all the way down. So do also look for a hardware reason why the sound might not be audible.)

Comment: This is not directly relevant, but I strongly suggest that you make `AV_audio_player` a `@property` and access it thru the property. Using ivars directly, without accessors, is a very poor idea.

Comment: Also I would just point out that since you say "this file used to play last week", it ought to be trivial to use your `git` repository to see what you changed that caused the code to stop behaving as you expect.